# Dynamic linq query iterating through list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

So trying to iterate through a session key, add all those values to a list, then for each value i want to compare it to a database table, and if the productid = id from value, then I want it to return that in the query.

```
 List<product> products = new List<product>();
            if (Session != null)
            {
                List<int> ids = Session["myIds"] != null ? (List<int>)Session["myIds"] : null;
                if (ids != null)
                {

                    //var grabProducts = db.products.Where(p => p.product_id == ids[0]);
                    foreach (int id in ids)
                    {
                        //ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("select * from customer where id={0}", id));

                        //int newd = id;
                        prodIds.Add(id);


                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < prodIds.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int newd = prodIds[i];
                        products = db.products.Where(p => p.product_id == newd).ToList();
                    }

                    var grabProducts = products;
                    return View(grabProducts.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6));
                }
            }
```

'db' is a instance of my EF model, and prodIds is a List() declared as a global.

Basically this is only getting me the last product from the list, which makes sense because I'm not cantonating 'products' i am only redeclaring it each time. How can I achieve this?

I tried a `products.Add(db.products.Where(p => p.product_id == newd)).ToList();` with no prevail, I tried the common C# syntax to cantonate `products += db.products.Where(p => p.product_id == newd).ToList();` also with no prevail.

Again, I am trying to iterate through a list of ints that contains id values, i want to then do a linq query to see what values in my database match the value from the id values (product_id = id value) and return all as a list of 'product' (product is a class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer. In order to do that you need to use the 'Contains' operator. As follows:

```
                var test = prodIds.Cast<int>().ToList();
                var grabProducts = db.products.OrderBy(p => p.product_id).Where(p => test.Contains(p.product_id));
```

Just incase anyone else runs into this problem, just declare a var to cast whatever datatype you need. Then do your query, and in the `.Where` selection you can do what I did and add a query that if a row contains any of the values in the list, return that. You will need an OrderBy before the Where though.